# Merging two tables by date-time sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL and I need a query to join two tables with specific conditions.The two tables are:
Table 1:

```
visitIp         serverTimePretty    lastActionDateTime
66.87.114.131   8/12/2015 22:59     8/13/2015 2:59
66.87.114.131   8/12/2015 20:32     8/13/2015 0:32
66.87.114.131   8/12/2015 19:34     8/12/2015 23:34
66.87.114.131   12/13/2015 17:36    12/13/2015 22:36
66.87.114.131   4/23/2016 10:25     4/23/2016 14:27
```

Table2:

```
IPAddress   StartDate
66.86.114.131   4/23/2016 8:25
66.70.114.131   4/23/2016 8:25
66.71.114.131   4/23/2016 8:25
66.72.114.131   4/23/2016 8:25
66.87.114.131   4/23/2016 8:25
```

Ip address is the Primary key in Tabe 2 and it references VisitIp in Tabe 1. Now i want the columns where Table1.visitIp= Table2.IPAddress and Table1.serverTimePretty - Table2.StartDate >= 2 hours. What would be the SQL query for that.

Comment: Which RDBMS? You have 3 tagged.

Comment: Which RDBMS? You have 3 tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below in sql server using DATEDIFF for hours part :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.visitIp = t2.IPAddress AND
       DATEDIFF(hour, t1.serverTimePretty, t2.StartDate) >= 2
```

**EDIT**

As earlier you didn't mention what type of DB you are using . For oracle the below query will work , Oracle directly provides you to do subtraction between two dates :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.visitIp = t2.IPAddress AND
       floor((date1-date2)*24) >= 2
```

Comment: It says: No such column: hour

Comment: Even if i run it as a  standalone statement its giving the same error. SELECT DATEDIFF (hour,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05'). Took this from w3schools and its showing the same error.

Comment: Apparently DATEDIFF does not work for Oracle Database

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_ADD()` with `INTERVAL 2 HOUR` in your join condition:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.visitIp = t2.IPAddress AND
       t1.serverTimePretty >= DATE_ADD(t2.StartDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: It shows some syntax error. Its on the date matching condition as when i run it without the And part it works fine

Comment: I gave you a MySQL answer.  The answer would be different in SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: o ok,,,will try it out